# NSDateFormatter format

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsdateformatter, gmail-api

I am trying to create the formatter for parsing `Fri, 12 Feb 2016 17:09:53 +0800 (SGT)` date format.

I tried using `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z`, but the output was null.

Any ideas as to how to parse the above date using `NSDateFormatter`.

Thank you in advance.

*P.S - Tagged in Gmail API, since I was receiving the same from its response.*

Comment: Are you sure you get null? Because i try it and it will get response.

Comment: @JAGAT Tried the same with another example >> Mon, 01 Feb 2016 23:11:25 -0800 (PST)
Didn't seem to work.

Comment: The NSDateFormatter is well documented, the latest iOS versions are declared to use the following specification http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table Unfortunately lower case z doesn't seem to work for the 'SGT' but it would work for 'PST'.

Comment: @A-Live: Yeah that seems to be the issue. :( Dunno how I can enforce Gmail API to send me the dates in the correct format.

Comment: Which API are you using ? Perhaps there's a way to specify the desired dates format or a library to handle the responses.

Answer (score 2):

set Date format as

> Uppercase Z for a numeric time zone offset

```
EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ (zzz)
```

for additional Information see this [link](http://fanfictions.xyz/questions/4516539/how-to-parse-these-time-zones-with-nsdateformatter)

Comment: Thank you @Anbu.
That solved half the problem.

However, the issue is with SGT. This only reads `EST` & `UTC`.

Need to figure out how I can enforce Gmail API to send the `Date` header in a particular format.

Thank you nonetheless. :)

Comment: @footyapps27 -- what else u need bro, if I knw I surely support you , can y explain what else u need

Answer (score 0):

Its better to handle **Timezone** separate from `NSDate` as `NSDate` store a point in time with either your **local timezone** or **UTC timezone**. Its upon you to handle these timezone.

So I would recommend that you cut off the time zone in parenthesis and just parse the numerical time zone offset before it. That way, you can convert all strings into an NSDate instance in UTC and you shouldn't have any problems parsing the strings.

Use this format: @"ccc, d LLL YYYY HH:mm:ss Z"

[Reference took from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14059019/3824808) and for more help regarding NSDateFormatter you can create your date format more easily from [this link](https://tahabebek.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/format-string-for-the-iphone-nsdateformatter/).